# Cakephp save multiple records in one model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have problem to save multiple records in a single table. This is my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Attendance');?> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Attendance</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($students as $key => $student): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $student['LectureParticipant']['name']; ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Attendance.'.$key.'.student_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$student['LectureParticipant']['student_id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Attendance.'.$key.'.lecture_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$student['LectureParticipant']['lecture_id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Attendance.'.$key.'.date', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>date("Y-m-d"))); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    echo $this->Form->input('Attendance.'.$key.'.participant', array(
                        'label' => false,
                        'div' => false,
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => array(
                            '1' => 'Present',
                            '0' => 'Absent',
                        ),
                    ));
                ?>
            </td>               
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<center>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('class'=>'greenBtn', 'div'=>false));?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link("Cancel", array('action' => 'viewTeacherClass'), array( 'class' => 'button redBtn')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
</center>
```

and this is my controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Attendance->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Attendance has been saved.');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'programmes', 'action' => 'viewTeacherClass'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add attendance.');
    }
}
```

This is my data structure:

```
array(
    'Attendance' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'student_id' => '1',
            'lecture_id' => '2',
            'date' => '2013-08-02',
            'participant' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'student_id' => '2',
            'lecture_id' => '2',
            'date' => '2013-08-02',
            'participant' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

I got this warning:

`Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2045]`

`Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Hash::numeric() must be an array, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\ibae\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php on line 2045 and defined [CORE\Cake\Utility\Hash.php, l`

I'm not sure what goes wrong here. I guess because of this warning, I cannot save all the data.

Comment: Look at the code in [`Model.php` on line 2045](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/a643295e4c48681d26d775d6f50a395e194eaf04/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2045), the `$data` argument is passed directly to `array_keys()`, so `$this->request->data` seems to be `null`.

Comment: I already debug($this->request->data) and it is not null

Comment: Well, if that is really the case, and the code you've posted is really the code where the error is triggered, then please check the code of `Model.php` in your specific CakePHP version (you should always mention the exact version number in your question), do some debugging (for example a `var_dump($data)` right before the `Model::saveAll()` in the controller, and inside of the `Model::saveAll()` method to check what the method actually receives) and if that doesn't get you on the track to fix the problem, then please update your answer with your debugging results.

Comment: I use cakephp2.0. I'm not sure why it is null in the model.php line 2045. I have used $this->Attendance->saveMany($this->request->data) and it also did not work. Finally, I did try and error with this  $this->Attendance->saveMany($this->request->data['Attendance']) and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using saveMany instead of saveAll ?

Comment: I used this $this->Attendance->saveMany($this->request->data['Attendance']) and it works